# Работа с двумерным ArrayList

Tags: java

Вводится таблица построчно в консоль, до тех пор пока не встретится пустая строка, ячейки в строке разделяются символом `|`. Нужно записать таблицу в двумерный `ArrayList`, а затем вывести на консоль. Не могу разобраться, что с моим кодом не так

Пример таблицы:

```
|test|me|one two|
|a|three spaces|famous|
```

Мой код:

```
package com.company;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mass = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    int i = 0;
    String current = "";

    while ((current = sc.nextLine()).length() > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> row = new  ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(current.split("|")));
        mass.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        for (int j = 1; j < row.size() - 1; j++) {
            mass.get(i).add(row.get(j));
        }
        i++;
    }

    ArrayList <Integer> introw = new ArrayList <Integer>();

    for (int j = 0; j < mass.size(); j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < mass.get(j).size(); k++) {
            System.out.print("|" + mass.get(j).get(k));
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }

}
}
```

Скриншот работы моей программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Метод `split("|")` принимает в качестве аргумента регулярное выражение, где символ `|` является служебным и его нужно экранировать - `split("\\|")`. В противном случае строка делится после каждого символа.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, только у меня еще вопрос к вам, если строка начинается с "|" и заканчивается "|" , то что будет записано в первый и последний элемент массива ArrayList, полученного split("\\|")

Comment: @sergeyka если исходная строка начинается с `|` - первым элементов массива после `split()` будет пустая строка; если заканчивается на `|`, то последним элементом будет часть строки между последними двумя разделителями (пустой строки в конце не будет).

Comment: Понял, спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @sergeyka можно сначала найти количество разделителей в строке и использовать метод `split("\\|", n)`, где `n` - найденное число, тогда и первый, и последний элементы в массиве будут пустыми строками.

Comment: Я вот так сделал for (int j = 1; j < row.size(); j++) {